# 23.98 fps video freezing in Blender 3.0.0

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm working on a video edit in a blender project that's a number of years old. It's using video that was recorded at 23.98 FPS. Older versions of Blender were able to handle this. However, after upgrading to 3.0.0, the video clips are frozen.
When I try inserting a 23.98 fps video into the sequence, Blender thinks it's only 1 frame long.
Any idea of how to get 23.98 fps video clips to work in blender 3?
Thanks

Comment: did you verify the video works properly by trying to import it into another video editor? any chance you can share this video so i can try importing it?

Comment: Try in Blender 3.2.